# My Desktop is in my Favorites folder instead of my home directory

Tags: windows-7, file-management

This is really weird. I don't know why this is. In every win7 computer I've ever used my desktop is located in `C:\Users\username\Desktop`

but on my laptop, it is in `C:\Users\username\Favorites\Desktop`

I can't figure out how to Google this, I keep getting hits about how to make your desktop show up in your favorites, but my desktop folder is physically in the favorites folder. It doesn't exist anywhere else.

Also, whenever I try to do something on my desktop like move a file to the trash I get a warning box saying:

These files might be harmful to your computer. 
Your Internet security settings suggest that one or more files may be harmful. Do you want to use it anyway?

I've tried disabling this in IE and my Win7 protection level. Nothing seems to work.

I don't know what other relevant info I can give.

I'm using Win7 Professional SP 1 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

I've done this to my users by accident many times. You can actually choose the folder in which your Desktop and other library folders resides.

Check C:\Users\username\ and see if there's two Desktop folders (there likely is). Right click on one and select properties. Look for the Location tab. If it's not there, select the other Desktop folder.

[image]

Click the `Move...` button and select the *other* Desktop folder in your home directory. If you can't tell the two apart, right click one and look for the location tab again (that's the one you **don't** want). If there isn't another one, right click and create a new folder named Desktop then select the folder.

Double check the path listed in the properties box (you don't want to dump the contents of your Desktop somewhere unintended. It's a pain...) Hit `Select Folder` and click `Apply`. You'll get a dialog box asking if you want to copy everything over to the new location. Select `Yes` (unless you want to abandon all the old files of course).